# typescript Property 'options' does not exist on type of Union type

Tags: angular, typescript, union-types

I have a couple of interface and a union type:

```
export interface FieldOptions {
  value: string | number;
  viewValue: string;
}

export interface BaseField {
  id: string;
  derived?: boolean;
  required?: boolean;
}

export interface NumberField extends BaseField {
  type: 'number';
  decimals: number;
}
export interface SelectField extends BaseField {
  type: 'select' | 'select-multi';
  options: FieldOptions[];
  source?: string;
}

export type Field = NumberField | SelectField;
```

As I understand that when I use my union type Field, it mains a field can be either Number or Select.

With that knowledge, I have a function in my Angular Component

```
getField( key: string ): Field {
  return this.fields.filter( el => el.id === key )[ 0 ];
}

getFieldVersion2( key: string ): any {
  const field = this.fields.filter( el => el.id === key )[ 0 ];
  if ( (<SelectField>field).options ) {
    return field as SelectField;
  } else {
    return field as Field;
  }
}
```

With only the function `getField` which is called in my template to get a Field object, in this case a Select with an Options array of view/viewValues, I get a build error on TS:

```
Property 'options' does not exist on type 'Field'.
   Property 'options' does not exist on type 'NumberField'.
```

In my understanding Field is a union type of either Number or Select. One of those has an `options` property, the other one doesn't.

So I created `getFieldVersion2` to hopefully solve the issue. However, unless I add `any` as a result type of my function, it will trigger a build error.

The template where the `options` are being used which triggers the compile error:

```
<mat-form-field  class="input">
  <mat-select formControlName="state">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of getField( 'state' ).options" [value]="option.value">
       {{option.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

What is going on, and what should I do better?

Comment: Seems like the error you're encountering is code that tries to actually use `getField` and possibly read the `options` property that may or may not exist; can you post that code as well? `getFieldVersion2` doesn't really do anything differently than `getField` at runtime because all of the TypeScript types you declared in your example disappear when compiled down to JavaScript.

Comment: exactly. However during compile time of typescript, the compiler is happy with `getFieldVerstion2`. I will amend my question and add the tempalte code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an interface that does not have an "options" property.  You then set your "Field" type equal to that interface (or potentially equal to another interface that does have the "options" property).

You are then attempting to call the "options" property that may or may not exist.  This is why you are receiving the ts error when compiling.

Switching the return type to "any" works because the compiler will not try to guess the type of object you are returning (therefore it is plausible that "options" will be a valid property and therefore no error should be thrown).

If you are going to call the "options" property on the "Field" type, you should make sure it exists before trying to compile your ts script.

Perhaps updating your methods to "getSelectField" and "getNumberField" would be a better option....but of course there are multiple ways you could handle this.

Comment: isn't what I am doing in `getFieldVersion2` a form of type checking and returning the correct Interface? It still doesn't work unless I return `any` from that function

Comment: okay, I did realize I the `getField` function is only used for fields with options, so I can make it more specific and call it `getOptionsField` which returns a type of SelectField (or later on a union type of RadioField or SelectField). I was just a bit intrigued to see the TS error in the template.